# write a carriage return to a file in cloud shell

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud

I have a file which is havig `'\n'` at the end of each record of a given file. I would like to have `'\r\n'` at the end of each record.

I tried below but upon checking on notepad++.. see same line seperator `'\n'` only.

```
awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' /home/vikrant_singh_rana/line_sep_file.csv >> new_test.csv
```

Comment: Looks fine. Use `od -c new_test.csv` to distinguish the kind of newlines.

Comment: Read `man unix2dos`.

Comment: As far as I understand, Notepad++ is a Windows program? But you have tags for Linux and Google Cloud here, so in case you transfer your files from one environment to another, make sure there's no translation happening there. The awk command you have is fine. e.g. `echo foo | awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' |od -c` gives `0000000   f   o   o  \r  \n` etc.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command unix2dos for this:

```
unix2dos file.csv
```

to install on debian:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```